# meaning of 'play point'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> What made Tinder Tinder was the work of a team: Joe Munoz, who built
>   the technical back end; Jonathan Badeen, who wrote the iOS code;
>   Christopher Gulczynski, who created the design; Rad, who played point.

What was Rad doing for Tinder? What is the meaning of the the phrase 'played point'?

[Source article](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2014-07-02/tinders-forgotten-woman-whitney-wolfe-sexism-and-startup-creation-myths).

Comment: ***point guard** basketball* A position in basketball usually reserved for the team's best ball handler and/or best passer. It is sometimes referred to as "the one". http://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nba/point-guard.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expression means :

> to take the lead on a campaign, program or project.

From: [Point man](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point+man)

> - someone who is the forefront of an important enterprise; "he is the president's point man on economic issues"
> - etymology: the "point man" is generally the person in charge. The "point guard" in basketball is the player that runs the teams offense. His main objective is to score points.

Also: [Run point.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=run%20point)